# Suds(SOAP) and wsdl namespace

Tags: python, django, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to access Iran's Mellat Bank Gateway and they don't have a well written document so they've sent me a PHP Example of what I want to do in python 2.7.10(django 1.9.4).
There are 2 files:

1. `default.php`
2. `callback.php`

There is a part which the first file indicates:

```
$client = new soapclient('https://bpm.shaparak.ir/pgwchannel/services/pgw?wsdl');
$namespace='http://interfaces.core.sw.bps.com/';
```

And after introducing data into `$parameters`, it'll call the soap method:

```
$result = $client->call('bpVerifyRequest', $parameters, $namespace);
```

How can I do the same in python? I'm using [suds](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/suds) (and have no problem whatsoever in changing it).

Is this even necessary to use or am I just wasting my time?

You can find the entire code in [here](https://gist.github.com/MHM5000/c39149f741575228b647e15fa85e2a6f)

Comment: actully i want to do that in php so can you give me the link of php file

Comment: You can ask the bank's support to send you the files. Tell me if you were unable to find it. (They will email you with an attachment)

Comment: hello @MHM5000 there is only one file is missing nusoap.php,
so can you give me the link for  nusoap.php file

Comment: it's an opensource project: https://github.com/deviservi/nusoap